# UItextfield listeners/methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I've got a couple UITextfield questions.

1. Is there a way to force the 'x', that clears out the textfield, to not hide when the user is not focused on the textfield?
2. Also is there a method that can detect the touch on the clear? didClearTextField or something?

thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `UITextField` and `UITextFieldDelegate`? See `UITextField clearButtonMode`.

Comment: SO FAQ: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
Set `clearButtonMode` to `UITextFieldViewModeAlways`

2.
Implement the `delegate` method `textFieldShouldClear:`. Or `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and analyse the edit.